# Pandas keep rows where column values change at least twice

Tags: python, pandas

Good day,

I have a large dataset with columns that keep track of the scores each person obtains. Here is a sample of the dataset:

**In:**

```
data = [[7, 10, 10, 10, 10], [17, 10, 10, 10, 10], [18, 8, 10, 10, 10], [20, 10, 10, 9, 9], [25, 9, 8, 8, 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['person_id', 'score_1', 'score_2', 'score_3', 'score_4'])
df
```

**Out:**

```
    person_id   score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
0   7           10      10      10      10
1   17          10      10      10      10
2   18          8       10      10      10
3   20          10      10      9       9
4   25          9       8       8       7
```

I need to find the rows where the column values change at least twice. For example:

- Row 0: All values are the same, no change
- Row 1: All values are the same, no change
- Row 2: 1st and 2nd values differ, 1 change
- Row 3: 2nd and 3rd values differ, 1 change
- Row 4: 1st, 2nd and 4th values differ, 2 changes

That means that only row 4 meets my requirements.

**Thus, the desired output would be:**

```
    person_id   score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
4   25          9       8       8       7
```

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you had '10 9 10 9' how many changes would it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to count the number of unique values, per rows, limited to the "score*" columns.

You can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on the rows after getting the correct columns with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html). Then slice:

```
df[df.filter(like='score').nunique(axis=1).gt(2)]
```

If you really want the changes from left to right so that A->B->A->B counts for 3 changes:

```
df[df.filter(like='score').diff(axis=1).ne(0).sum(axis=1).gt(2)]
```

output:

```
   person_id  score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4
4         25        9        8        8        7
```

Comment: @Mozway : Nice. Maybe I would use `df.filter(like='score').diff(axis=1).ne(0).sum(axis=1).sub(1).ge(2)` or comment to emphasize we need to substract `1` as `.ne(0)` brings back the first column in the sum. I may also use `df.filter(like='score').diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).sum(axis=1).ge(2)`

Comment: @hpchavaz Are you sure? Which pandas version do you use? I don't have the issue

Comment: @Mozway, 1/ My comment is related to the A>B>A>B part, which is the interesting one. 2/ your code gives the right rows, no problem. 3/ I often use google colaboratory which is always some version late, (pandas 1.3.5), but I do not think this is related with the version.

Comment: I don't get the comment on "*brings back the first column in the sum*", it won't as the column was dropped, no? If you think the answer can be improved feel free to edit or suggest an edit ;)

Comment: `diff` sets the first element of the axis (here first column) to `NaN`, which, after `ne(0)`, becomes `True`. I edited my previous comment to add a version with `iloc` which may be the most understandable.

Comment: @hpchavaz OK I see, I thought you were talking about the **"person_id"** column >_<. Well it doesn't matter as this first column will always be True, so why bother adding operations? `gt` is perfect for this case I think

Comment: @Mozway, No, `df.filter(like='score')` has already removed `person_id` I 'm just trying to keep the code explicit by not doing several things at once. In your code, `.gt(2)` is correct because it takes into account the +1 added by a column of `NaN` .

Comment: Yes this was the way I intended it, I guess mostly a design choice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mozway's answer for the case A->B->A->B counts is brillant:

```
df[df.filter(like='score').diff(axis=1).ne(0).sum(axis=1).gt(2)]
```

A more plain answer, based on Mozway's one could be :

```
df[ # following lines build a boolean mask
    df.filter(like='score')     # keep only scores columns
      .diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:] # diff the columns and keep all except the first one whose values are all `NaN`
      .ne(0).sum(axis=1)        # count changes: values that differ from 0 
      .ge(2)                    # finish the boolean mask: changes >= 2
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[((df.set_index('person_id').diff(axis=1)
     .fillna(0)!=0).sum(1)>1).reset_index(drop=True)
]

  person_id  score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4
4         25        9        8        8        7
```